# Table with text from side of page to the middle

Tags: tikz-pgf, margins, rounded-corners

I would like to place a table from the side of the page to the middle with rounded corners.
For example like this:
[image: Left the start of the left side of the page]

But I can't find anywhere how to do it.
I can draw the image with Tikz but than I can'f fill it.
I can draw a table with rounded corners around the text that goes in the table, but I can't place it just outside the margin.

EDIT
The point of the document is to get two columns and some graphics between paragraphs.
This questions is about the gray part at the bottom of the image. I would like the text in it with the same margin as the rest. But the grey color is perfect this way.
All the text that is entered needs to be automatically returned to a new line.
Additionally the second column needs to be at the same height as the OVerview chapter.
I first made this with multicols but with that added the grey table could not be inserted.
[image]

And the code

```
\begin{document}

\basicPage

\productCode{Order code}
\topHeaderLine{
    Title row 1 \newline
    Title row 2
}

\makeHeader

\Large

\section{Overview}
\lipsum[1]

%\vbox{
\begin{table}[!ht]
    \begin{adjustwidth}{-2cm}{}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (table) [outer sep=5mm]   {
            \begin{tabular}{c}
            \Large
            text in row 1 but needs to be here      \\
            \Large
            text in row 2 but needs to be here      \\
            \Large
            text in row 3 but needs to be here      \\
            \Large
            text in row 4 but needs to be here      \\
            \Large
            text in row 5 but needs to be here          \\
            \Large
            text in row 6 but needs to be here          \\
            \Large
            text in row 7 but needs to be here          \\

            \end{tabular}
        };
        \scoped[on background layer]\fill[LightGrey,rounded corners=4mm] 
        (table.north west) -| (table.south east) -- (table.south west);
        \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{adjustwidth}
\end{table}

\vbox{
    \section{Applications}

    \begin{itemize}
        \item[$\bullet$] Point1.
        \item[$\bullet$] Point2.
        \item[$\bullet$] Point3.
        \item[$\bullet$] Point4.
        \item[$\bullet$] Point5.
    \end{itemize}
}


\section{Benefits}
\vbox{  
    \subsection{SubTitle}
    \lipsum[2]
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! So you want it to go to the margin or the page edge itself? Also, the table is left-aligned?

Comment: I want to use a margin for text etc. but not for this table, so it looks in a pdf it is at the edge of the paper.

Comment: Is it just one table?

Comment: Please provide a complete example. Nobody can compile your code as it stands. We need enough of the preamble for the example to work. What is `\basicPage`? How is `\productCode` defined? What does `\makeHeader` do? Your document includes numerous macros whose meanings we don't know.

Answer (score 1):

As starting point:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[showframe,
            margin=30mm]{geometry}

    \begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
    \begin{table}[!ht]
\begin{adjustwidth}{-\marginparwidth-2\marginparsep}{}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
11111111111111  &   22222222222222  &   33333333333333     \\
    \hline 
    \end{tabular}
\end{adjustwidth}
    \end{table}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

for more, you need provide more data (actually you say in question that rounded corners and table is not the problem). Above MWE gives:

[image]

Addendum, that drawing of bacground of tables is the probelm (see comment of Alenanno), than see if the following suggestion lead to what you looking for:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds, scopes}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[showframe,
            margin=30mm]{geometry}

    \begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
    \begin{table}[!ht]
\begin{adjustwidth}{-\marginparwidth-2\marginparsep}{}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\node (table) [outer sep=2mm]   {
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
11111111111111  &   22222222222222  &   33333333333333     \\
    \hline 
    \end{tabular}
                };
\scoped[on background layer]\fill[gray!20,rounded corners=4mm] 
    (table.north west) -| (table.south east) -- (table.south west);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{adjustwidth}
    \end{table}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

Above solution work fine in one side documents, for two side the solution is (far more) more complicated. If you have latter case, let me know.

Comment: I think he wanted the background too with rounded corners.

Comment: @Alenanno, from OP question I understand that background and rounded corners are not the problem, only how to move this to page border.Now, after second thought I thing that you have right. SO I added to my answer how to make bacground.

Comment: Wow thanks that is exactly what I need, great work!

Comment: I see one problem, because it doesn't work together with multicols, I use these to make two columns

Comment: @maartenMeta, you should say this in your question. Please edit it, provide minimal, complete document, which we can compile, which will show, what you like to achieve. Let me remind: I start my answer with "As starting point" , since your question is very unclear.

Comment: I hope this is better

Comment: @maartenMeta, unfortunately no much )to me). We (at list me) need the code. Image can serve as illustration what you get from code or what you like to get (this is not clear) ...

Comment: Sorry forgot that one...